# How to merge 2 lines in perl script

Tags: perl, perl-module

I am trying to write a Perl script that will transform the input

```
( name  
  ( type ....  
  )  
)
```

into the output

```
( name  ( type ... ) )
```

I.e. all these lines matching `( )` are merged into a single line and I want to update the original file itself.

Thanks in advance

Comment: That's 4 lines. looks like you just want to convert newlines to spaces.

Comment: You might want to look at the core module [Text::Balanced](http://perldoc.perl.org/Text/Balanced.html), though it might well be overkill for your current problem.

Comment: I believe my answer should help you out.

Comment: You'll have to be careful if there are comments interleaved within the sets of 4 lines, like on the line containing `( name`.  I did something like this with some C++ and had to make sure the comments with leading `//` didn't end up in the middle of the merged line.

Answer (score 1):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file="t.txt"; #or shift (ARGV); for command line input
my $new_format=undef;

open READ, $file;
local $/=undef; #says to read to end of file

$new_format=<READ>;
$new_format=~ s/\n//g; #replaces all newline characters with nothing, aka removes all \n

close(READ);

open WRITE, ">$file"; #open for writing (overwrites)
print WRITE $new_format;
close WRITE;
```

This works, assuming that the entire file is one big expression.  For reference, to remove all white-space, use `$new_format=~ s/\s//g;` instead of `$new_format=~ s/\n//g;`. It can be easily modified to account for multiple expressions.  All one would have to do redefine `$/` to be whatever you're using to separate expressions (for example if simply a blank line: `local $/ = /^\s+$/;`) and throw everything into a while loop.  For each iteration, push the string into an array and after the file is completely processed, write the contents of the array to the file in the format that you require.

Answer (score 0):

Is the ((..)) syntax guaranteed? If so I'd suggest merging the whole thing into one line and then splitting based on )(s.

```
my $line = ""; 
while(<DATA>) 
{ 
 $_ =~ s= +$==g;  # remove end spaces.
 $line .= $_; 
}
$line =~ s=\n==g;
my @lines = split /\)\(/,$line;
my $resulttext = join ")\n(", @lines; 
print $resulttext;



__END__

( name  
 ( type ....    
 )  
)  
( name2   
  ( type2 ....  
  )  
)    
( name3  
 ( type3 ....  
 )  
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<>) {
    chomp unless /^\)/;
    print;
}
```

Usage: `perl script.pl inFile [>outFile]`

Sample data:

```
( name  
  ( type ....  
  )  
)
( name_a  
  ( type_a ....  
  )  
)
( name_b  
  ( type_b ....  
  )  
)
```

Output:

```
( name    ( type ....    )  )
( name_a    ( type_a ....    )  )
( name_b    ( type_b ....    )  )
```

The script removes the input record separator unless the line read contains the last closing right paren (matched by being the first char on the line).

Hope this helps!